# Automatically moving through various views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am using two AutoCompleteTextViews followed by two EditText views that are implementing datePickerDialog, a CheckBox and a Button. My aim is to dynamically move from one view to another so that when I click on one of the autocompletes or select dates it moves to next view.

I used focusable to move from first AutoCompleteTextView to another but it seemed a bit useless as I first had to select one of autocompletes and only then press enter. Is there a way to make more dynamic transition from such view?

Also, if I add focusable on views with datePickerDialog, the calendar stops working. Therefore, the flow stops at the second AutoCompleteTextView, clearly highlighting it. Any suggestions how to make this process as dynamic as possible?

Here is my xml for better understanding:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/location_from"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/departure_loc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/location_to"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/holiday_loc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:clickable="true"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/departure_date"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:hint="@string/dep_date"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/return_date"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:hint="@string/return_date"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/direct_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/direct_only"/>


</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/search_button"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Comment: Read this .. : https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation when pressing enter the "nextFocusXXX" should jump to the next view

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Itzik but my problem is that I can't make EditText views focusable and therefore the flow gets stuck there. I've tried nextFocusForward or nextFocusDown but it stops before the datePickerDialog in an EditText